# better approach to common object in two classes

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following classes (note some properties removed for brevity

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Customer Data class holds all high level customer Data
    /// </summary>
    public class CustomertData
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }

        public IList<Car> AvailableCars { get; set; }

        public IList<CustomerUnit> CustomerUnits { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Customer Unit holds all data relating to a customer unit
    /// </summary>
    public class CustomerUnit
    {
        public int? CutsomerUnitId { get; set; }

        public int? UnitIndex { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public IList<Car> CustomerUnitCars { get; set; }   
    }
```

As can be seen the customer data class contains a list of CustomerUnits and also a list of AvailableCars - the CustomerUnit class then contains a list of cars which have been added to that unit.

The Car class has a property of assigned which is a bool and then an int CarId and some other properties which aren't relevant for what I am doing.  I return from my WebAPI a CustomerData object.  For the available cars I want to show them all.  Any which have been assigned to a unit get set to true while the remaining are false.

I am currently doing this with the code below and it is working as expected just wondering is there a better approach perhaps using linq - I was trying to do some googling and it appears using intersect may be the approach to use but not getting the desired output using it.

```
                

                var customerUnits = customerData.CustomerUnits;

                var carIds = new List<int>();

                if (customerUnits.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var customerUnit in customerUnits )
                    {
                        customerUnit.CustomerUnitCars.ToList().ForEach(c => c.Assigned = true);

                        foreach (var customerUnitCar in customerUnit.CustomerUnitCars)
                        {
                            carIds.Add(customerUnitCar.CarId);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(carIds.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var carId in carIds)
                    {
                        foreach (var availableCar in customerData.AvailableCars)
                        {
                            if(availableCar.CarId == carId)
                            {
                                availableCar.Assigned = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really a good site for "what's a better approach?" kinds of questions because, at least in most questions, there's no objective definition of "better" or "best". If this is your own code, and you want critiques on all aspects of the code, it might work on [codereview.se], but please do read their help center before posting.

Comment: Do note, on Code Review, it is required that all relevant code be posted for the sake of reviewers, and not just snippets of that code.

Comment: Something like Resharper should be able to refactor that code into Linq for you.  Last I heard they had a 30 day free trial > https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/ .  I have nothing to do with them, just recommend it from time to time to improve people's code.

Comment: @RandomUs1r I have used resharper begore and found it excellent. I Am trying to get current company to get licences for it as it I feel it even speeds up navigation around visual stdio but the company are yet to be convinced

Comment: @Mike - Thanks I have used code review in the past but find it gets alot less user traffic than SO

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely simplify (or "intersect" as you call it) some of the logic, if that's what you're looking for:

```
if (customerUnits.Any())
{
    foreach (var customerUnit in customerUnits)
    {
        customerUnit.CustomerUnitCars.ToList().ForEach(c => c.Assigned = true);
        foreach (var customerUnitCar in customerUnit.CustomerUnitCars)
        {
            carIds.Add(customerUnitCar.CarId);
            customerData.AvailableCars
                .Where(availableCar => availableCar.CarId == customerUnitCar.CarId)
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(availableCar => availableCar.Assigned = true);
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind, once you get into nested for loops and LINQ, you're code will become less and less readable. I personally don't have an issue with your current implementation.

Also, check out https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. If you post the code there, you'll likely get a more in-depth review.

Comment: Yeah that is one think I found with resharper where sometimes it would reactor code that is readable and maintainable into a complex linq query so guess there is a balance to be struck